# How to print all methods of Fixnum class in ruby

Tags: ruby, class, methods

I want to print all methods of Fixnum class in ruby. When i typed `Fixnum.methods` it give this type of output that i don't understand.

```
[:allocate, :superclass, :<=>, :module_exec, :class_exec, :<=, :>=, :==, :===, :include?, :included_modules, :ancestors, :name, :public_instance_methods, :instance_methods, :private_instance_methods, :protected_instance_methods
```

Comment: "it give this type of output that i don't understand." - yes, those are names of methods, which you can call on Fixnum. What did you expect to see instead?

Comment: “it give this type of output that i don't understand”—this is a statement, not a question.

Comment: What's your expected result / output?

Answer (score 2):

You probably wanted the instance methods:

```
Fixnum.instance_methods
```

To filter the ones from `Object`:

```
Fixnum.instance_methods - Object.instance_methods
```

Comment: There is also `Fixnum.instance_methods(false)` for only those declared on `Fixnum`. And, IMHO, it makes more sense to filter out `Kernel.method`, rather than `Object.methods`.

Comment: @mudasobwa `false` filters stuff from [`Numeric`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Numeric.html) as well.

Comment: It all depends on the OP's definition of "methods of Fixnum". This could be the methods owned by Fixnum or the methods Fixnum responds to or anything in-between, i.e. methods inherited from Integer, Numeric, Comparable, Object, Kernel, and / or BasicObject (_if_ we are talking about instance methods).

Answer (score 1):

Consider installing `pry`

`pry` is a better version of `irb` that allows to do browse classes and object "as if they were folders". See for example

```
$ pry
[1] pry(main)> ls Fixnum
Object.methods: yaml_tag
Fixnum#methods: 
  %   +   <    ==   >>   bit_length  fdiv       odd?  to_f   ~
  &   -   <<   ===  []   div         inspect    ord   to_s 
  *   -@  <=   >    ^    divmod      magnitude  size  zero?
  **  /   <=>  >=   abs  even?       modulo     succ  |    
[2] pry(main)>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a ruby array and method names are expressed in symbols (another ruby stuff). You could do

```
Fixnum.methods.each { |method| puts method }
```

From ruby 2.4.0 and later

```
Integer.methods.each { |method| puts method }
```

Comment: just `puts Integer.methods` :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev `Integer.methods.each(&method(:puts))` is cleaner, isn’t it?

Comment: @mudasobwa doesn't like blocks, I'm sure :D

Comment: @mudasobwa: all that elixir is affecting your thinking, I see. :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev it makes me sane back ;)

Answer (score 0):

The output you get is an array of method names as symbols. So, if you want to print them do it like this:

```
Fixnum.methods.each { |method| puts method }
```